# Wreath product of finitely generated groups is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-group-theory, wreath-product

Let $G$  and $H$  be two groups generated by finite sets $\Sigma_G$ and $\Sigma_H$, and let $W=G \wr H$  be the wreath product of $G$ and $H$. Show that $W$ is finitely generated by $\Sigma_G \times \{1 \} \cup \{1 \} \times \Sigma_H$.

I cannot prove this. Please advice to me.

Comment: How do you identify an element of the form $(g,1)$ for some $g\in G$ with an element in the wreath product?

Comment: thank you to answer , but I cannot understand your question.

Comment: An element of the wreath product has the form $(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_{|H|},h)$ with each $g_i\in G$ and $h\in H$. It is not clear how you wish to identify an element of $G\times \{1\}$ with an element in the wreath product.

Comment: Oh…I see.I understand your question, but I cannnot understand how to identify an element of (g,1) in G × {1} with an element in the wreath product.

Comment: An element of the wreath product has the form (g_1 ,g_2 ,…,g_|H| ,h)  with each g_i ∈G  and h∈H. So, The wreath product is generated by Σ_H ∪{Σ_G_h  ∣h∈H}. thus, Σ_G ∪ Σ_G ∪ Σ_G ... ∪ Σ_G ∪ Σ_H = Σ_G ∪ Σ_H. Is this idea right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $G \wr H= \left( \bigoplus\limits_{h \in H} G_h \right) \rtimes H$ where $G_h$ is a copy of $G$. Therefore, $W= G \wr H$ is generated by $\Sigma_H \cup \{ \Sigma_{G_h} \mid h\in H \}$, and so by $\Sigma_H \cup \bigcup\limits_{h \in H} h \Sigma_G$ or by $\Sigma_H \cup \bigcup\limits_{h \in \Sigma_H} h \Sigma_G$. Finally, you can deduce that $W$ is generated by $\Sigma_H \cup \Sigma_G$.

Comment: Thank you to answer. In my text , definition of the wreath product is C_C(H;G) ⋊ H . where C_C(H;G) is the set of finitely supported function (f:G→H).So, how do you identity this set with (⨁_h∈H G_h )?

Comment: I think $C_C(H;G)$ should be the set of finitely supported functions $H \to G$. Such a function $f : H \to G$ can be viewed as $(f(h)) \in \bigoplus\limits_{h \in H} G_h$ (in particular, $f(h) \in G_h$).

Comment: I see! I can understand!.Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is W generated by  by Σ_H ∪⋃_{h∈H} hΣ_G   or by Σ_H ∪⋃_{h∈Σ_H}  hΣ_G ?? And,does G_h mean that {f(h)|f∈C_C(H;G)} ??

Comment: I understand that the group G_h means the group G.

Comment: If a group $A$ (resp. $B$) is generated by $S_A$ (resp. $S_B$) then any semi-direct product $A \rtimes B$ is generated by $S_A \cup S_B$ since $A \rtimes B= AB$. Here, it is the same thing. Another key remark is that $\Sigma_{G_h}=h^{-1} \Sigma_{G_1}$ (in my answer, I did not distinguish $\Sigma_{G}$ and $\Sigma_{G_1}$).

Comment: IS G_h a copy of G ? Then, Is this relation tha Σ_G_h = Σ_G right ?

Comment: I mentionned in my answer that $G_h$ is a copy of $G$, and $\Sigma_{G_h}$ is the generator set of $G_h$ associated to $\Sigma_G$.

Comment: A copy means that G_h = G , so Σ_G_h = Σ_G . Is this idea wrong?

Comment: It is correct (even if it is not exactly an equality formally).